# dotnet build error CS1056: Unexpected character in content files

Tags: .net, build, nuget

I have several Nuget packages that contain only content that is used as static resources in the target projects.

Example from the .nuspec file:

```
<files include="**/Resources/*" buildAction="Content" flatten="false" copyToOutput="true" />
```

When installing those packages in the new type of projects (VS2017) they add content files as references with the appropriate attributes (Content and Copy if newer in my case).
However when building the target project the build fails with the following errors:

```
error CS1056: Unexpected character 'ñ'
error CS1056: Unexpected character '˜'
```

and so on.

Result is the same if specify buildAction="None"

I expect them to be included in the build output as well as in resulting package when publishing via `dotnet publish` command

Could someone please advise what I do wrong?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone is curious: the problem was in this string: `**/Resources/*`
One "*" does not apply condition to the sub directories, if any, so files there got compiled as the source files instead of content.
Obviously there should have been "**" or exact path to the content files